# Combining Authentication using Azure AD with Username Password Stored in Database

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

Currently, i am building web application + web API that have authentication using two options. There is a landing page (login page) that ask user to choose to authenticate via:

1. (Internal) Azure AD
2. (External) Username & Password

If choosing Azure AD, then it will redirect to login.microsoftonline.com.
If choosing Username & Password, then it will ask user to input username and password. Later on it will verified through Database (Master User).

I have setup my Web Application and my Web API via Azure AD.

The question:

- How do i authenticate user that is accessing using external account (via username & password)?
- Can create 1 dummy account in Azure AD (example emailxxx.onmicrosoft.com) and perform authentication under this account for all my external account? I see some of my option is using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow (ROPC), but it is not recommended.

Comment: Are the external users you are talking about as guest users?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal

Comment: Yes, but i want to create 1 guest users for all my external users because they will login not using password stored in Azure AD, but coming from my application Database Master User. I managed to perform ROPC by using AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword from IPublicClientApplication. How do i perform impersonation for Azure AD Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add guest users to Azure ad, see:  [Add Azure Active Directory B2B collaboration users in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-users-administrator).

> How do i authenticate user that is accessing using external account
> (via username & password)?

You can verify whether the logged-in user is a guest user by verifying the `acct` claims of the access token.  If the user is a member of the tenant, the value is `0`. If they are a guest, the value is `1`.

[image]

> Can create 1 dummy account in Azure AD (example
> emailxxx.onmicrosoft.com) and perform authentication under this
> account for all my external account? I see some of my option is using
> Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow (ROPC), but it is not
> recommended.

You can add an external account as a guest to the Azure ad tenant, and then use [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) or [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to perform authentication.  (However, based on security considerations, Microsoft recommends that you do not use ROPC flow. This flow requires a very high level of trust in the application and brings risks that are not present in other flow. This flow should only be used when other, safer flow cannot be used.)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is accurate for the guest account. ROPC Flow only help to perform Web API calling but does not grant authentication for Web Application Controller. Anyway, after reading online for this topic... i don't think MSAL does not provide impersonation login. I will close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flow that i want to achieve:
[My Web Application Authentication Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTBiD.png)

After going through the forums everywhere i can conclude that:

- MSAL does not support Login Impersonation => i am trying to perform after username password verification in DB, system can automatically perform Azure AD Sign In as Guest Acccount (1 Federated Account for all External Users) which skip the login page login.microsoft.online.com.

To achieve this, i am using Dot Net Core session as the main authorization for all the controller in my web page. If does not exist, then system will redirect to Login page.